# Importing phin nodejs client result in `p is not a function`

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to import the popular library `phin` ([1M+ download / week](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phin)). I then import the library, and use it as described by the documentation. I get the following error: `p is not a function`.

[Here is a code sandbox example to try it out](https://codesandbox.io/s/node-playground-forked-zjnt17?file=/src/index.js).

Comment: https://github.com/ethanent/phin/issues/50#issuecomment-667516909 not sure if this helps

Comment: No, it's not what I'm looking for :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to recreate the error in a local environment and solve it by removing the `* as` from the import statement.

### Code

```
import p from "phin";
//    ^ removed * as

// a short iife for testing
(async () => {
  let res = await p("https://google.com");
})()
```

Comment: It seems right, but on my local environment, I have to use `import * as p from "phin`. On code sandbox, I have to use `import p from "phin"`. The correct statement is different depending on some parameters I can't define  

Comment: That is very interessting as ```import * as p from "phin``` did not work in my environment nor Codesandbox. But I also cannot put my finger on why it is so.

Comment: javascript module are so strange... It's not the first time I stumble upon weird behaviors like this one.